# How can I make Jelastic start PM2 to launch an 'npm' command instead of a file?

Tags: pm2, jelastic

I'm using a Jelastic Node.js PM2 environment and I want my app to be started with something like the following:

```
pm2 start npm --name "app name" -- start
```

(my server is **not** a JS file).

The command runs fine if I use a Jelastic 'npm' environment, but I'd rather have the benefits of PM2.
I tried setting various `APP_FILE` (`start`, `npm start`, a pm2 config file path), Entry Points and `PROCESS_MANAGER_FILE`, without success. I usually get this error:

```
Node ID : 53209
-----------------------
result 1 Failed to start 
Stopping nodejs server[  OK  ] Starting nodejs server [FAILED]
```

Comment: You may try achieving it through an ecosystem file as in the following manual: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/ . 
Based on the manual, it is required to create a file and specify the executable command in 'script'. After, you will need to specify the path to this configuration in the PROCESS_MANAGER_FILE variable. Please notice that this config should be readable by the Jelastic user.

Comment: Thank you @Jelastic, that was correct. I just used `APP_FILE` instead of `PROCESS_MANAGER_FILE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment from @Jelastic worked! Indeed using a PM2 'ecosystem file' works in Jelastic.

Set `APP_FILE` (or possibly `PROCESS_MANAGER_FILE`) to `ecosystem.config.js` (This is relative to `ROOT_DIR`)

The content of this file should look something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      script: "yarn",
      args: "--cwd myserver1 start",
      name: "myserver1",
    },
    // You can use this setup to start multiple processes too.
    {
      script: "yarn",
      args: "--cwd myserver2 start",
      name: "myserver2",
    },
  ],
};
```

`--cwd` tells yarn to switch the Current Working Directory. If you use npm, you can use `--prefix` instead.

Read more about PM2 ecoystem files: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/